# SQL for Pivot and AVG using MySQL database version 5.5.62

Tags: mysql, pivot

Using this query on MySQL database version 5.5.62

```
SELECT
    COUNT( CASE WHEN MONTH ( tData ) = 1 THEN 'Jan' END ) Jan,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN MONTH ( tData ) = 2 THEN 'Feb' END ) Feb,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN MONTH ( tData ) = 3 THEN 'Mar' END ) Mar,
    tname,
    AVG( DATEDIFF( COALESCE ( tClosed, tOpen ), tData )), 1 ) 
    END AS `avg` 
FROM
    `tbl_2021` 
WHERE
        tname IN ( 'ST00' ) 
GROUP BY
    MONTH ( tData );
```

the return is

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
| Jan   | Feb   | Mar   | tname | avg |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
| 17970 |     0 |     0 | ST00  | 8.4 |
|     0 | 14429 |     0 | ST00  | 5.2 |
|     0 |     0 | 22685 | ST00  | 0.4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```

but I would like to have instead something like:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| Jan   | Feb   | Mar   | tname | avg_Jan | avg_Feb | avg_Mar |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| 17970 | 14429 | 22685 | ST00  |   8.4   |   5.2   |   0.4   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Any help would greatly appreciate... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CASE statement in the AVG function in the same way as the COUNT function.
Also, it isn't necessary to use a GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT
    COUNT( CASE WHEN MONTH ( tData ) = 1 THEN 'Jan' END ) Jan,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN MONTH ( tData ) = 2 THEN 'Feb' END ) Feb,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN MONTH ( tData ) = 3 THEN 'Mar' END ) Mar,
    MAX(tname),
    AVG( CASE WHEN MONTH ( tData ) = 1 THEN DATEDIFF( COALESCE ( tClosed, tOpen ), tData ) END ) avg_Jan,
    AVG( CASE WHEN MONTH ( tData ) = 2 THEN DATEDIFF( COALESCE ( tClosed, tOpen ), tData ) END ) avg_Feb,
    AVG( CASE WHEN MONTH ( tData ) = 3 THEN DATEDIFF( COALESCE ( tClosed, tOpen ), tData ) END ) avg_Mar
FROM
    `tbl_2021` 
WHERE
        tname IN ( 'ST00' )
```